# How do I get information from 2 SQL tables into 1 dataGridView in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I have a connection between my SQL query and C# and I have DataGridViews that display information from 1 SQL table but I want to know how to be able to display selected information (such as StudentID and StartDate from Student table and tuitionCode and RoomCode from Tuition table) and  from 2 SQL tables (Tuition table and Student table) and display the information in DataGridView1 in the C# visual studio.

Comment: Create a Sql query which returns data(collection or DataTable) your need - set result as datasource of datagridview: `DatagridView.DataSource = result`

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: I apologise and done, I'm new to this

Comment: Do you have sql query ready to retrieve data from two tables? Are using join or something to get the data? And you know how to execute that query from C# using ado.net? If you have tried all these things then what error ir issue you are facing while running this code?